# Global variable functions

Tags: python, global

I am using a method for storing and recalling global variables in Python. I like it. It seems to work for me. I am not a coder though. I know nothing about this stuff. So, wondering where its limitations will be - how and when I will regret using it in future.

I create a function that will update the value if passed a new one or return the existing value as below:

```
def global_variable(new_value = None):
    # a function that both stores and returns a value

    # first deal with a new value if present
    if new_value != None
        # now limit or manipulate the value if required
        # in this case limit to integers from -10 to 10
        new_value = min(new_value, 10)
        global_variable.value = int(max(new_value, -10))

    # now return the currently stored value
    try:
        # first try and retrieve the stored value
        return_value = global_variable.value
    except AttributeError:
        # and if it read before it is written set to its default
        # in this case zero
        global_variable.value = 0
        return_value = global_variable.value

    # either way we have something to return
    return return_value
```

## store like this

global_variable(3)

## retrieve like this

print(global_variable())

Comment: Why not just use a global variable?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: This function you've written would be much better off being a class.

Comment: If instead of 1 global variable you wanted 100, you would need to write this function again and again and again....  with different names each time.  Just using global variables is way easier BUT if you wanted to keep going with this object that stores global variables for you, I would suggest a class instead of just a function. That would allow you to extend this to 100s of variables without all the tedious work.

Comment: This is something like defining a property for a class which you will only create one instance for; `global_variable(x)` is the same as `singleton.value = x` and `global_variable()` is the same as `singleton.value`.

Comment: Since Python implements something called a "global variable", you're doing yourself a disservice by creating new functionality with the same name.  If you have to specifically store and retrieve it with function calls, it's not a global variable in the sense most of us expect.  The implementation you give strongly suggests that you expect some sort of class object functionality.  This strongly indicates that you need to work through more Python tutorials on applicable techniques before you try to code a solution to whatever problem you're solving.

Comment: "Why not use global variables?" Good question. Because this contains all of the logic around the setting the variable. Limits, default, validation, generating exceptions for illegal values if necessary etc.

Comment: "Class instead of a function." Great suggestion thanks, I will try it.

Comment: So, the functional difference with using a class as far as I can tell...

+ve Multiple variables, that share the same rules -> multiple instances (as mentioned above)
+ve You can recall the same data in different ways - fraction or percentage for example

-ve The variable function self-instantiates (and of course you can only have one instance)
-ve To set a value in a class with rules applied (boundary checking etc.), you have to use a function so it reads differently from the equivalent recall (e.g. set and get)

A class can do more but just considering in this context.

Comment: Aran-Fey "This function you've written would be much better off being a class." I found a couple of reasons but in your opinion why would one be much better off?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use global variables. If you need to change them within a function you can use the global keyword:

```
s = 1
def set():
    global s
    s = 2
print(s)
set()
print(s)

> 1
> 2
```